# Why does one app launch faster than the other?

Tags: android

I'm curious about this. I have an app called GoSMS PRO and an app called Contacts+ installed in my phone. They both popup an alert notification when a text message is received. However, GOSMS PRO always beats Contacts+'s popup. I was wondering how this was happening in a programming perspective? Is there a way to give a certain app more preference than the other.

Comment: GoSMS PRO might be doing less work before showing up the popup or the UI of Contacts+ app is taking a longer time to draw itself. Normally, a user would uninstall one of the two apps.

Answer (score 0):

From security and permission side every app from Google Play has similar privilege, if they are not signed by the certificate of device manufacturer. This also means that none of the app will get extra preference.

Some time app do many type of checking/initialization/loading before showing their UI and when this type of things happens apps take longer period to load or display UI.

Most common things people do

- Creating and initializing database
- Reading database.
- User validation (reading file)
- Device state scanning(network)

Most common case is database access. I wonder if the app reading Content Provider before showing UI it might take long time depending on your device hardware and number of contacts.

Key strategy would be showing the UI right way and load data in background. Android has  lots of Asynchronous api, just to avoid this type of scenario.